# Conversion to datetime from varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
 declare @FromDate varchar(30)
 set @FromDate= '2014-06-06'
```

I need to convert `@FromDate` to a `datetime`:

```
set @fromdate = convert(datetime,  @fromdate, 126)
```

Then I need the output in the format of `'2014-06-06 00:00:00.000'`.

Can anyone suggest how to perform this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FromDate VARCHAR(30) SET @FromDate = '2014-06-06'
DECLARE @FromDateDT DATETIME SET @FromDateDT =  @FromDate
-- DECLARE @FromDateDT DATETIME SET @FromDateDT =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @FromDate) -- It's the same as line above
SET @FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FromDateDT, 120)
SELECT  @FromDate
SET @FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @FromDateDT, 121)
SELECT  @FromDate
```

or simple

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-06-06'), 121)
```

Some other formats:

https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @FromDate varchar(30)
SET @FromDate= '2014-06-06'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, @fromdate), 21)
```